# Create a "time savings" calculator with dynamic figures

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, calculator

I've been tasked with creating a dynamic calculator on a webpage.

It will consist of the following:

1. Several figures that will be entered through the backend (Wordpress).
2. Several input area's where the customer will input figures.
3. And several figures that will change depending on what the customer enters.

There will be several calculations changing the figures on the page.

I can output the figures from WP easily it's just points 2 and 3 I'm struggling with. What's the best way to approach this? Can anyone post some simple examples incorporating the 3 points above?

**The one important element is that it has to recalculate figures on the fly - so no clicking submit buttons or anything along those lines.**

Comment: What exactly do you need to calculate, what are your values, and how will your values relate to each other? This is a fairly simple task (it's a javascript job, fairly obviously) but without knowing a bit more about what figures you have, what figures the user will enter, what results should be displayed, and in what format they should be displayed, its a little difficult to guide you further...

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for the reply. At the moment I'm just looking for examples so some basic calculations with some basic inputs that change dynamically would be great as I can take that further. I just have no idea of where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1**

```
<script>
var unitPrice = <?php echo $unitPrice; ?>;
...
</script>
```

**point 2**

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" onkeyup="updateTotal();/>
```

**point 3**

```
<span id="totalPrice"></span>

<script>
function updateTotal() {
    var quantity   = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
    if(isNaN(quantity)) quantity = 0;
    var totalPrice = unitPrice * quantity;
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerText = totalPrice;
}
</script>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/S6nAE/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple calculator I just threw together that works out the other properties of a circle from any one property. It makes use of the `onkeyup` event so the values are updated as you type. It is by no means perfect (not even 100% sure about the maths) but that is not the point, the point is to demonstrate how to do calculations and update the display in a live manner, and hopefully it will give you a push in the right direction.

It is far too complicated to explain in great detail here, so have a play with it and ask specific questions and I will answer them as best I can...

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Circle calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var radius, diameter, circumference, area, sphereVolume, lastRadius, lastDiameter, lastCircumference, lastArea, lastSphereVolume;

      function updateDisplays () {
        // This function updates the displayed values
        document.getElementById('radius_input').value = (isNaN(radius)) ? '0.0' : ((radius.toString().split('.').length == 1) ? radius.toString()+'.0' : radius);
        document.getElementById('diameter_input').value = (isNaN(diameter)) ? '0.0' : ((diameter.toString().split('.').length == 1) ? diameter.toString()+'.0' : diameter);
        document.getElementById('circumference_input').value = (isNaN(circumference)) ? '0.0' : ((circumference.toString().split('.').length == 1) ? circumference.toString()+'.0' : circumference);
        document.getElementById('area_input').value = (isNaN(area)) ? '0.0' : ((area.toString().split('.').length == 1) ? area.toString()+'.0' : area);
        document.getElementById('spherevolume_input').value = (isNaN(sphereVolume)) ? '0.0' : ((sphereVolume.toString().split('.').length == 1) ? sphereVolume.toString()+'.0' : sphereVolume);
        // Track the last values
        lastRadius = (isNaN(radius)) ? 0 : radius;
        lastDiameter = (isNaN(diameter)) ? 0 : diameter;
        lastCircumference = (isNaN(circumference)) ? 0 : circumference;
        lastArea = (isNaN(area)) ? 0 : area;
        lastSphereVolume = (isNaN(sphereVolume)) ? 0 : sphereVolume;
      }

      window.onload = function () {

        // All these functions calculate the other values based on the one that has changed

        document.getElementById('radius_input').onkeyup = function () {
          radius = parseFloat(this.value);
          if (lastRadius == radius) {
            return;
          }
          diameter = radius * 2;
          circumference = Math.PI * diameter;
          area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
          sphereVolume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
          updateDisplays();
        };

        document.getElementById('diameter_input').onkeyup = function () {
          diameter = parseFloat(this.value);
          if (lastDiameter == diameter) {
            return;
          }
          radius = diameter / 2;
          circumference = Math.PI * diameter;
          area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
          sphereVolume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
          updateDisplays();
        };

        document.getElementById('circumference_input').onkeyup = function () {
          circumference = parseFloat(this.value);
          if (lastCircumference == circumference) {
            return;
          }
          diameter = circumference / Math.PI;
          radius = diameter / 2;
          area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
          sphereVolume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
          updateDisplays();
        };

        document.getElementById('area_input').onkeyup = function () {
          area = parseFloat(this.value);
          if (lastArea == area) {
            return;
          }
          radius = Math.sqrt(area / Math.PI);
          diameter = radius * 2;
          circumference = Math.PI * diameter;
          sphereVolume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
          updateDisplays();
        };

        document.getElementById('spherevolume_input').onkeyup = function () {
          sphereVolume = parseFloat(this.value);
          if (lastSphereVolume == sphereVolume) {
            return;
          }
          radius = Math.pow((sphereVolume / Math.PI) * (3/4), 1/3);
          diameter = radius * 2;
          area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
          circumference = Math.PI * diameter;
          updateDisplays();
        };

      };
    </script>
    <style>
      #title {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      td.property_name {
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
      }
      td.property_formula {
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="title">Circle Calculator</div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="property_name">Radius:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="radius_input" value="0.0" /> cm</td>
        <td class="property_formula"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="property_name">Diameter:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="diameter_input" value="0.0" /> cm</td>
        <td class="property_formula">2r</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="property_name">Circumference:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="circumference_input" value="0.0" /> cm</td>
        <td class="property_formula">2&#960;r</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="property_name">Area:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="area_input" value="0.0" /> cm<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td class="property_formula">&#960;r<sup>2</sup></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="property_name">Volume of Sphere:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="spherevolume_input" value="0.0" /> cm<sup>3</sup></td>
        <td class="property_formula"><sup>4</sup>&frasl;<sub>3</sub>&#960;r<sup>3</sup></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

A much simpler example that just does 1 addition:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Simple Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      window.onload = function () {
      // All code here is executed once the document has finished loading

        // Assign a function to num1's onkeyup event
        document.getElementById('num1').onkeyup = function () {
          // Declare the variables
          var num1, num2;
          // Get the values in variables with the correct type for calculations
          num1 = parseFloat(this.value);
          num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
          // Update the answer display
          document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = num1 + num2;
        };

        // Assign a function to num2's onkeyup event
        document.getElementById('num2').onkeyup = function () {
          // Declare the variables
          var num1, num2;
          // Get the values in variables with the correct type for calculations
          num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
          num2 = parseFloat(this.value);
          // Update the answer display
          document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = num1 + num2;
        };

      };

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="num1" size="4" value="0" /> + <input type="text" id="num2" size="4" value="0" /> = <span id="answer">0</span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'll see what I can work out from that. Was looking for something a bit simpler like a+b=c kind of simple! With a= a wordpress field, b=an input and c=the answer. All done on the fly so without having to click a submit button or reload the page.